# App crashes on any User interaction after Parse.User Query

Tags: android, parse-platform, crash

I've been busy writing an android app with the Parse.com framework and I'm having a problem with a function which makes my app crash.

Everytime I query a user that's not the logged in user, the result returns without a problem, but it crashes the app. Than I restart the app and from than on every function I call which handles any Parse.com interaction (with a user field?) crashes my app. Even after restarting my app al Parse.com functions (which worked before executing the user query) immediately spike my memory and crash the app within seconds.

I'm pretty sure my user query is not the problem but I'll add it below:

```
public void getUser() {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("objectId", "QjY2tSVMtL");
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // The query was successful.
                // check if we got a match
                if (user == null) {
                    // no matching user!
                } 
                    Log.i(TAG, user.getUsername());
                }
            } else {
                // Something went wrong.
            }
        }
    });
```

The query runs just fine, the user's username returns in my log and nothing bad happens untill then, right after the log entry it crashes. On restast I run another function, which results in the memory spike, and than a crash.. done.

The only way to fix my app is to remove the , remove the app from my phone, remove the installationId of my phone from Parse.com and then reinstall the app.

What I did notice is. If I run the query, it does not mather whether the callback method contains any code or not. It just crashes

This is a log from a couple of days ago showing the errors I still get when I run my ParseUser query and than continue using the app: (http://bit.ly/1DTCbwj)

If anyone know's what might be wrong, I'd love to hear it because I'm all out of ideas...

Comment: do you have static members?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes! There can only be one user with the same objectId (there's just a few debug users in total now and I created all so there are no identical users)

Comment: change it to non static. give it a try

Comment: I wouldn't know how to be honest. I'm not a seasoned developer, just an enthousiastic hobbyist..

Comment: please show me the Logcat, I need to see the error

Comment: That's the logcat showing the error's I seem to get everytime: http://bit.ly/1DTCbwj

Comment: If you are getting too much information, you are storing them somewhere in your app, so you need to release the container of that information or whatever the name is.plzremove all static modifiers for the mean time and try to copy more code

Comment: The only other user reference I use (quite often) is Parse.User.getCurrentUser().*** so that shouldn't be a problem. There's also no static functions in my code.